# Live Bar graph with d3 in js using data from realtime firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to javascript and have been stuck at a problem for the better part of 2 weeks. I am trying to make a bar graph that updates in real time using data from Firebase. The structure of my database is:
 
               title:
                  -------child1
                  -------child2
                  -------child3
                  -------child4

The data to firebase is provided from a python script that is working perfectly and is updating every child of title every 10 seconds.
I made a bar graph that is updating automatically via random number generation.

```
   //Return array of 10 random numbers
var randArray = function() {

    for(var i = 0, array = new Array(); i<10; i++) {
        array.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*10 + 1))
    }
    return array
}

var initRandArray = randArray();
var newArray;



var w = 500;
var h = 200;
var barPadding = 1;
var mAx = d3.max(initRandArray)
var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, mAx])
                .range([0, h])

var svg = d3.select("section")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)

svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(initRandArray)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("x", function(d,i) {return i*(w/initRandArray.length)})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return h - yScale(d)})
    .attr("width", w / initRandArray.length - barPadding)
    .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d)})
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
    return "rgb(136, 196, " + (d * 100) + ")";
});

svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(initRandArray)
    .enter()
    .append("text")
    .text(function(d){return d})
    .attr("x", function(d, i){return (i*(w/initRandArray.length) + 20)})
    .attr("y", function(d) {return h - yScale(d) + 15})
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("fill", "white")

setInterval(function() {

    newArray = randArray();

    var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")

    rects.data(newArray)
        .enter()
        .append("rect")

    rects.transition()
        .ease("cubic-in-out")
        .duration(2000)
        .attr("x", function(d,i) {return i*(w/newArray.length)})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return h - yScale(d)})
        .attr("width", w / newArray.length - barPadding)
        .attr("height", function(d){return yScale(d)})
        .attr("fill", function(d) {
            return "rgb(136, 196, " + (d * 100) + ")";
        });

    var labels = svg.selectAll("text")

    labels.data(newArray)
        .enter()
        .append("text")

    labels.transition()
        .ease("cubic-in-out")
        .duration(2000)
        .text(function(d){return d})
        .attr("x", function(d, i){return (i*(w/newArray.length) + 20)})
        .attr("y", function(d) {return h - yScale(d) + 15})
        .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
        .attr("fill", "white")


}, 3000)
```

[Live bar chart on random number](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTcOB.png)

I need to update the chart using the data from firebase. I already know how to connect firebase to js using the snapshot and have already tried it to no avail.
Also, need some help with the styling of the graph.
Please if anybody knows how I can finish this(its time sensitive).
Here's the code link in jsfiddle: [Live bar chart d3](http://jsfiddle.net/uwqk9y4n/)

Thanks

Comment: If you've already tried reading from Firebase, show the code that you tried. I highly recommend reading [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is the best way to ask for help with questions like this.

Comment: You can probably break this challenge into at least 2 smaller questions. As it stands, there is a huge gap between what you have and what you want.